# How to use `ctrl + shift + 3` as shortcut key binding. Currently it switches to `ctrl + pagedown ctrl + shift +`

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

As title is pretty much clear, I want to assign custom shortcut key to `ctrl + shift + numpadKeys` but it looks like they produce different key combinations. Like `ctrl + shift + 6` changes to `ctrl + right ctrl + shift +`